# Java: обойти необходимость невозможного изменения значения локальной переменной извне

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

**Задача**

- При нажатии `FloatingActionButton` кнопка должна повернуться (в результате чего иконка "плюсик - добавить" привратиться в "крестик - отменить") и должно появиться всплывающее окно `popupWindow`;
- При повторном нажатии `FloatingActionButton` кнопка доложна принять исходное положение, а окно - исчезнуть.
- Тоже самое должно произойти при касании вне зоны `popupWindow`

Первые два пункта полностью реализуются через `OnClickListener()`. Для реализации третьего есть метод `PopupWindow.OnDismissListener()`, но одно но - ему "по барабану" на кнопку, что и является источником проблемы, рассматриваемой в данном вопросе.

**Решение**

```
private void initFAB(){
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    //...
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popup_window,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Срабатывает только при нажатии на кнопку
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        // Триггер; в начальном состоянии окно убрано
        boolean fABShowMenu = false;

        public void onClick(View view) {

            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true); 

            if (!fABShowMenu){ // должно выполняться, когда окно убрано
                rotateFabForward();
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(fab, Gravity.END | Gravity.BOTTOM, 50, 400);
                fABShowMenu = true; // теперь окно показано
            }
            else{ // должно выполняться, когда окно показано
                rotateFabBackward();
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                fABShowMenu = false; // теперь онко убрано
            }
        }
    });

    popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(){

            rotateFabBackward();
            //fABShowMenu = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Данное решение работает, но если закрыть окно касанием вне его, то при повторном нажатии на кнопку оно не откроется, потому что триггер `fABShowMenu` по-прежнему имеет значение `true;`.

- В идеале для решения задачи нужно одно - из метода `setOnDismissListener` изменить значение `fABShowMenu = false;`. Но нельзя - это локальная переменная другого метода.
- Объявить переменную без инициализации вне метода `setOnClickListener` мы не можем - будет `Variable ... accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final`. Сделать её `final` без инициализации бессмысленно, а если инициализировать, то на входе `if (!fABShowMenu){` условие всегда будет `!false`, т. е. `true`.
- Запихнуть `setOnDismissListener` внутрь `OnClickListener()` можно, но тогда при нажатии на кнопку с целью закрыть меню будут "выстрeливать" сразу два события - `Dismiss` и `Click`. Как показывает эксперимент, `onDismiss` вернёт `false`, заетм сработает `onClick` с этим значением на входе и в `else` (куда нам нужно) мы не попадаем.

Что-нибудь можно сделать, кардинально не меняя решение?

---

**Обновление**

> В идеале для решения задачи нужно одно - из метода `setOnDismissListener` изменить значение `fABShowMenu = false;`.

Прошу прощения, ерунду сказал. Даже если каким-то невероятным образом сделать то, что я сказал, то выполнится метод `onClick`, в который мы придём с `fABShowMenu = false;`, и меню тут же откроется. При нажатии на FAB, когда меню открыто, происходит два события, и в этом вся проблема.

Comment: Потому что вы зачем-то храните состояние внутри слушателей. У вас есть, де-факто, конечный автомат, описывающий состояние этой менюшки, и слушатели UI, которые должны им управлять, вызывая open, close, toggle и/или аналоги, но сама ручка управления менюшкой должна лежать вообще отдельно от слушателей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У любого UI элемента в Андроид есть поле `tag`, которое идеально подходит для таких случаев как ваш. Т.е. сама кнопка будет хранить состояние вторичного элемента и это значение можно менять отовсюду, откуда доступна сама кнопка.
От переменной `fABShowMenu` можно вообще отказаться, а начальное состояние задать прямо в XML разметке.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Попробую реализовать - тогда оценю Ваш ответ.

Comment: Попробовал с тагами. Всё работает, как Вы сказали, но осталась основная проблема: при клике на кнопку с целью закрыть меню происходят сразу два события: `Dismiss ` и `Click`. Вероятно, это уже претендует на отдельный вопрос.

Comment: `OnDismissListener` динамически задавайте и убирайте когда надо, чтобы не было лишних срабатываний.