# Избежать одновременного срабатывания OnDismissListener и onClick

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Этот вопрос является развитием темы [Java: обойти необходимость невозможного изменения значения локальной переменной извне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611477/java-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9?noredirect=1#comment839898_611477). Из ответов на вопрос я понял, что суть проблемы не та, котрую я изначально предположил, и она заслуживает отдельного вопроса.

Повторю задачу. У нас есть `FloatingActionButton;` при нажатии которого появляется диалоговое окно (или `popupWindow`, не суть важно), а при повторном нажатии - исчезает. Также окно должно исчезнуть при нажатии в любом месте вне окна.

```
private void initFAB(){
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupWindowContent = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window_content, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupWindowContent,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        if (fab.getTag().toString().equals("0")){
            rotateFabForward();

            View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //...
                }
            };

            // ...

            popupWindow.showAtLocation(fab, Gravity.END | Gravity.BOTTOM, 50, 400);
            fab.setTag("1"); // visible state
        }
        else{
            rotateFabBackward();
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            fab.setTag("0"); // hidden state
        }
    }
});

popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            rotateFabBackward();
            fab.setTag("0");                   
        }
    });
}
```

Если закрывать окно только касанием вне окна, но без кнопки, то всё будет нормально. При нажатии же на кнопку с целью закрыть окно срабатывают два события: `Dismiss` и `Click`. Одновременно они срабатывают, или последовательно, не знаю, но так или иначе, `OnDismissListener` заканчивает выполнение раньше и мы приходим в `onClick` с нулевым тагом и в `else` не попадаем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что-нибудь можно сделать? Может есть аналог `stopPropagation` из JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться AlertDialog'ом c лиснерами для каждой кнопки и отдельным слушателем для всего диалога(setOnDismissListener), если я правильно понял вашу проблему.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    b.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    b.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    });
```

Обновлено. При использовании AlertDialog'a греется бэкграунд, что показывает пользователю, чтобы он не нажимал на кнопку меню еще раз, ибо это не логично. А все "внимание" передается на диалоговое окно.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за решение. К сожалению, пока не понимаю, как оно решает задачу. У меня всего 3 слушателя - для кнопки FAB, слушатель для касания вне окна `OnDismissListener` и не рассматриваемый в данной задаче слушатель для кнопок в окне. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на FAB с целью убрать окно срабатывают сразу два слушателя, потому что `OnDismissListener` случает всю зону вне окна, в том числе и кнопку `FAB`.

Comment: Вы хотите использовать повторное нажатие на фаб-кнопку? Если да - то попробуйте сделать логику на основе булевых значений, типа была ли нажата кнопка.

Comment: Да, повторное нажатие на FAB-кнопку должно закрыть меню. Это я [уже реализовал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611477/java-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9), как Вы сказали.

Comment: Проблема всё та же: нужно что при повторном нажатии на FAB срабатывал только её слушатель, а `dismissListener` - не срабатывал. Иначе в `onDismissListener` будет записано `false` (меню скрыто) и мы затем выполнится `onClick`, в который мы придём с этим значением `fasle`, и только что закрывшееся меню снова откроется.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, похоже, что вы неверно задаете логику для срабатывания OnDismiss

Comment: А поподробнее? Разве `onDismiss` не имеет уже встроенной логики? То есть, срабатывает когда окно открыто при нажатии вне окна.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Для удобства выведите в лог, когда срабатывает какой слушатель, чтобы отпали такие вопросы. Посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232724/popupwindow-dismiss-when-clicked-outside